# How to smoothen the edges from an image obtained from imagesc function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, matlab-figure, rgb

I have an RGB image obtained from saving the imagesc function as shown below. how to refine/smoothen the edges present in the image.

[image]

It consists of sharper edges, where I need to smoothen them. Im not able to find a solution for performing this for an RGB image. Instead of the staircase effect seen in the image I'd like to even out the edges. Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179988/how-to-trace-the-surface-area-as-well-as-smoothen-a-specific-region-in-an-image)?

Comment: In my previous question I had done segmentation and masking to smoothen the image. I wanted to know if there are other ways to do it for colour images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe `imresize` will help you:

```
% here im just generating an image similar to yours
A = zeros(20);
for ii = -2:2
    A = A + (ii + 3)*diag(ones(20-abs(ii),1),ii);
end
A([1:5 16:20],:) = 0;A(:,[1:5 16:20]) = 0;
subplot(121);
imagesc(A);
title('original')
% resizing image with bi-linear interpolation
B = imresize(A,100,'bilinear');
subplot(122);
imagesc(B);
title('resized')
```

**EDIT**

here I do resize + filtering + rounding:

```
% generates image
A = zeros(20);
for ii = -2:2
    A = A + (ii + 3)*diag(ones(20-abs(ii),1),ii);
end
A([1:5 16:20],:) = 0;A(:,[1:5 16:20]) = 0;
subplot(121);
imagesc(A);
title('original')
% resizing
B = imresize(A,20,'nearest');
% filtering & rounding
C = ceil(imgaussfilt(B,8));
subplot(122);
imagesc(C);
title('resized')
```

[image]

Comment: Resize is making the image look blurred!!! How to overcome the staircase effect that has been generated? Thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

**solution**

use imfilter and fspecial to perform a convolution of you image with gaussian.

```
I = imread('im.png');
H = fspecial('gaussian',5,5);
I2 = imfilter(I,H);
```

change 'blurlevel' parameter (which determines the gaussian kernel size) to make the image smoother or sharper.

**result**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I would like to even out the edges that look like a staircase in the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for straighter edges, like an elevation map you can try [`contourf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html).

```
cmap = colormap();
[col,row] = meshgrid(1:size(img,2), 1:size(img,1));
v = linspace(min(img(:)),max(img(:)),size(cmap,1));
contourf(col,row,img,v,'edgecolor','none');
axis('ij');
```

This produces the following result using a test function that I generated.

[image]